Cannot extract the day from a Date form field
The (trivial!) code snippet below does not work:
d = getField("Date1").value;
day = d.getDay();
this.getField("Day").value = day;

I am trying to run this code snippet in a PDF Form document:
Line 1: reads a date from the Form's Date Field "Date1" and saves it to d
Line 2: Gets the day of the week from d
Line 3: Inserts "day" in the Form's numerical field "Day"
It does not work. What am I doing wrong there?
Thanks
I was expecting to see the day of the week (numerically) appear in the in the result (numerical) field "Day".

In Acrobat it's a bit more complex, as you need a field string including the year to form a DOW calculation.
Several offered about the web but basically since I use ISO dates this works for me.

var string = this.getField("Date1").valueAsString;
event.value = "";
if (string!="") {
    var date = util.scand("yyyy-mm-dd", string);
    if (date!=null) this.getField("Day").value = util.printd("ddd", date);
}

Modify fields strings and trigger as required. System DOW uses Sunday default as 1, for example:

var days = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];  //1=Sunday
var string = this.getField("Date1").valueAsString;
event.value = "";
if (string!="") {
    var date = util.scand("yyyy-mm-dd", string);
    if (date!=null) {
    this.getField("Day").value = util.printd("dddd", date);
    this.getField("Day2").value = util.printd("ddd", date);
    num = days[date.getDay()];
    this.getField("Day3").value = num;
    }
}

For Monday to be day 1 of week change first line
var days = [ "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ];  //position 1=Sunday

